# Object reference not set to to an instance of an object in Dropdown List in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Am trying to find out why the system giving me this error in visual studio ",i populate the dropdown from the database and it has values at runtime, but when i click the submit button i get the above error, wondering what am i doing wrong here.
  here is my code      // this is the model

```
public class LeaveRequest
{
    public string TableTypecode { get; set; };
    public string TableTypeName { get; set; };

    [Display(Name = "Selected TypeCode")]
    public int SelectedTableTypeCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadedTableTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And below is how am fetching the data from sqlserver .. works well.

```
  public class OpenTypeList
    {

         public List<LeaveRequest> OpenList()
         {
             string hasconnections = 
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leaveConnections"]
                 .ConnectionString;

    List<LeaveRequest> P2 = new List<LeaveRequest>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(hasconnections))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewTypes", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListName", "status");
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                LeaveRequest pom = new LeaveRequest();
                pom.TableTypecode = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(0));
                pom.TableTypeName = dr.GetString(1);
                P2.Add(pom);
               }
            }
              return P2;
        }


     }
}
```

so here i populate the list from my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LeaveRequestIndex(LeaveRequest pleave)
    {
        var modal = new LeaveRequest()
        {
            UserRoles = GetRoles(),
            LoadedTableTypeName = GetTypesIdz()
        };
        return View(modal);
    }
```

And lastly below is my razor code .. in the view

```
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestStatus)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTableTypeCode, 
    Model.LoadedTableTypeName, new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

This error is generated when i click the submit button.
     my post method is here...

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult LeaveRequestIndex(FormCollection fmcollection)
    {
        foreach (string key in fmcollection.AllKeys)
        {
            Response.Write("Key= " + key + "  ");
            Response.Write(fmcollection[key]);
            Response.Write("<br/>");

          }
        return View();
      }
```

Comment: So you are saying this error you are getting on submit.  So can you show us your post  method

Comment: been trying to see the keys each control on the form would return. but when i remove the dropdown list code it works

Comment: Because you do not repopulate the `LoadedTableTypeName` property in the POST method before you return the view so its `null`

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your models in post method also.  So update your post method like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LeaveRequestIndex(FormCollection fmcollection)
{
    foreach (string key in fmcollection.AllKeys)
    {
        Response.Write("Key= " + key + "  ");
        Response.Write(fmcollection[key]);
        Response.Write("<br/>");

    }

    var modal = new LeaveRequest()
        {
            UserRoles = GetRoles(),
            LoadedTableTypeName = GetTypesIdz()
        };
        return View(modal);
  }
```

Comment: oh thank you, its working ...

Comment: @Bels Then mark it as answer